# Interactive map with tmap does not appear in Shiny app, but does show in Rstudio viewer

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps, tmap

The interactive map I created with tmap does show up in the RStudio Viewer, however, if I try to include it in my Shiny application it does not appear. I've used the tmap_leaflet function, renderLeaflet and leafletOutput. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Below is an example code of what I used in my Shiny application:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(c(tmap,tmaptools,leaflet))

  ui <- fluidPage(
        leafletOutput("test"))

  server <- function(input, output) {

     output$test <- renderLeaflet({

     # data is a shapefile with geometry properties and a mapping variable and facet variable. 

     tmap_mode("view")   
     map  <- tm_shape(data) +
             tm_polygons() +
             tm_facets(by = "facet_variable",nrow = 2, ncol = 2) +
             tm_shape(data) +
             tm_fill(col = "mapping_variable",
                     legend.show = T, 
                     colorNA = "grey",
                     palette = "Reds",n=9) +
             tm_shape(data) +
             tm_borders("white",alpha=.8, lwd=1.5) +
             tm_layout(outer.margins = 0) +
             tm_view(view.legend.position = c("left","bottom"))
     tmap_leaflet(map,mode="view",show=T)
     })
    }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you include some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some dummy data I am able to see the map.

I am not sure if you can load packages like this : `library(c(tmap,tmaptools,leaflet))`
It gives me this error:

> Error in library(c(tmap, tmaptools, leaflet)) :    'package' muss
>   Länge 1 haben

And I dont think there is an argument called `view.legend.position`. Try with `legend.position` only.

I think the problem comes with the `facets`. (Example below doesnt use them)

```
library(shiny)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)

Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)

grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as(grd, "SpatialPolygons")
centroids <- coordinates(polys)
x <- centroids[,1]
y <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
ex_1.7 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys,
                                   data=data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z, row.names=row.names(polys)))
ex_1.7$face <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(2,50))


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("test"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$test <- renderLeaflet({

    # data is a shapefile with geometry properties and a mapping variable and facet variable. 

    # tmap_mode("view")   
    map  <- tm_shape(ex_1.7) +
      tm_polygons() +
      # tm_facets(by = "facet_variable",nrow = 2, ncol = 2) +
      # tm_facets(by = "face", nrow = 2, ncol = 2) +
      tm_shape(ex_1.7) +
      # tm_fill(col = "mapping_variable",
      tm_fill(col = "y",
              legend.show = T,
              colorNA = "grey",
              palette = "Reds",n=9) +
      tm_shape(ex_1.7) +
      tm_borders("white",alpha=.8, lwd=1.5) +
      tm_layout(outer.margins = 0) +
      tm_view(legend.position = c("left","bottom"))


    tmap_leaflet(map)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 
Without the facets it does also work fine with the original data:). 

Still wonder why it is not possible with the facets?

As for the libraries, that was a typo. I did load them separately in my file. 

Please note that the view.legend.position has recently replaced the legend.position inside the tm_view function (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/2.0/topics/tm_view).

Comment: Correct, I am still using tmap 1.11. I dont know how it would place the different facets on the map. Do you know of any example using facets on a tmap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tmap function to plot facetted maps together with the following code.
The resulting map is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gmJf.jpg

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

# Loading shape and select four largest cities in the Netherlands
country  <- read_shape("/local_directory/wijk_2017.shp")

# Cleaning and preparing data
cities   <- country %>% 
            filter(GM_CODE %in% c("GM0363","GM0599","GM0518","GM0344"),
                  !WK_CODE %in% c("WK036399","WK059999","WK051899","WK034499"))
cities   <- cities %>%
            mutate(WK_NAAM = as.character(WK_NAAM),
                 OPP_TOT = as.numeric(as.character(OPP_TOT)),
                 OPP_TOT = cut(OPP_TOT,breaks = c(-Inf,seq(500,2000,by=500),Inf)))

# Plotting facetted tmap of four largest cities in the Netherlands.
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(cities) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_facets(by = "GM_NAAM",
            nrow = 2, ncol = 2) +
  tm_shape(cities) +
  tm_fill(col = "OPP_TOT",
          legend.show = T, 
          colorNA = "grey",
          title = "Total area per neighbourhood",
          textNA = "No data",
          palette = "Greens",n=5,
          id = "WK_NAAM") +
  tm_shape(cities) +
  tm_borders("white",alpha=.8, lwd=1.5) +
  tm_layout(outer.margins = 0) +
  tm_view(view.legend.position = c("left","bottom"))
```